# Length of multicols.sty column rule and \fbox

Tags: minipage, multicol

If I typeset the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{2pt}

\fcolorbox{black}{yellow!25}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4in}%
        \begin{multicols}{2}%
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{multicols}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

I obtain this output:
[image]

The vertical column rule does not touch the horizontal lines of the `\fbox`. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: `\fbox` has padding of  length `\fboxsep` which you could set to 0pt or just put negative space of that amount at top and bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. the `multicols` introduces vertical space, that I remove with a negative `\vspace`, and
2. A `\strut` should be applied at the end of the material (note I needed `nopar` option of `lipsum` to svoid adding the closing `\par` automatically.)

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{2pt}

\fcolorbox{black}{yellow!25}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{4in}\vspace{-3pt}%
        \begin{multicols}{2}%
            \lipsum[1]\strut
        \end{multicols}%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider using a `tcolorbox` which is far more customizable than a standard `fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{2pt}

\begin{tcolorbox}[size=tight,width=4in,bottom=2pt,left=5pt,right=5pt]
        \begin{multicols}{2}%
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{multicols}%
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

you can set the box to 0 padding (`tight`) and then add custom paddings where you need to (e.g.: with 0 padding the vertical line crosses the bottom box border).

[image]